# I am getting extra column while converting .csv file to .xlsx file in Python

Tags: python, excel, csv

The code below converts .csv file in C:/Path/ into .xlsx file. However, it creates an extra column when converted to .xlsx file. How can I delete that added extra column? Thank you very much.

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/Processed_Report/", topdown=False)
for name in files:
    base_name, ext = os.path.splitext(name)  #Split name, extension
    if ext in ".csv":
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root, name))
        df.to_excel(os.path.join(root, 'Test.xlsx'))
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Try with `index=False`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `index=False` as a keyword of [`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).

Replace this :

```
df.to_excel(os.path.join(root, 'Test.xlsx'))
```

By this :

```
df.to_excel(os.path.join(root, 'Test.xlsx'), index=False)
```

Comment: I wonder why it defaults to `index=True`?

Comment: No need to answer dupes

Comment: @MarkRansom, there has been many discussions about that, https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/46583#issuecomment-1176850085

Answer (score 0):

that is just how it is with dataframes in pandas, when you create a dataframe by any mean (like csv file) it ads an extra column which contains the indexes.
how ever df to excel function has an argument name index which you can set on False to prevent creating that extra column:

```
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(root, name))
df.to_excel(os.path.join(root, 'Test.xlsx'), index = False)
```

Comment: No need to answer dupes.